# TigntVNC setup issue on XUbuntu

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I have installed tightvnc and openssh on a xubuntu server.

I am trying to debug why I get 'permission denied' error when I try to login from a remote machine.

On server:

```
vncserver

>>New 'X' desktop is ServerName:1

>>Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
```

On remote machine:

```
ssh user@serveripadress  works fine and I can login
```

On remote machine:

```
ssh -L 5910:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l user serveripaddress
```

fails with 'permission denied' after typing password for tightvnc

On server:

```
ssh -L 5910:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l user localhost
```

at password prompt I used the tightvnc password and got 'permission denied' (I also tried the user password with same response).

Server firewall rules

```
...
5901 ALLOW IN remoteipaddress
22   ALLOW IN remoteipaddress
...
```

Server VNC listening port:

```
lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen" | grep Xvnc

Xvnc    2229 user   5u  IPv4  37691      0t0  TCP localhost:5901 (LISTEN)
```

As I can login via ssh, and the vncserver is running I am not clear why I cant login to the vnc session

Answer (score 0):

I switched to TigerVNC and had same issues above. I managed to get this working by:

On Remote machine:

```
ufw allow out from any to serveripaddress port 5901
```

Then I could connect to the server using the TivergVnc viewer client with serveripaddress:1